# Unix job getting timeout while it is calling the spring boot api call through curl command

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unix

Unix shell script is calling through the curl command spring boot based endpoint.After some time unix job get timeout while the spring boot based endpoint continue to run in the background.How to remediate.How to ensure that unix job continue to be active as long as the spring boot based end point is running

Not able to fix the issue

Comment: could you please explain bit in details about functional details about your endpoint?

Comment: Please add more details on your spring application architecture. There are different ways to resolve this. Also for a long running job/script its not recommended to keep the blocking call of restful api. in such

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.